# How can I check whether aWord Document is opened? -- just to make title checker happy

Tags: django, dst

I originally used title "time problem in django, maybe related to daylight savings time adjustment", but I was always told "These word are not allowed" and I have no idea how to entitle my problem, so I have to use the current title to pass the title checker. Absurd!

Now is my problem. Please look at the image below:

[image]

The time in django is one hour later than the actual time (19:43 vs 18.43). I guess it may be because django forgot to hangle daylight savings time adjustment. How to fix this problem (so that django can adjust DST automatically, not manually after a few months when DST is not in effect in EDT time zone)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Time zone support is disabled by default. To enable it, set USE_TZ = True in your settings file. Installing pytz is highly recommended, but not mandatory. It’s as simple as:

`sudo pip install pytz`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/